# How to show data in gridview as a link format in yii2?

Tags: gridview, yii2

[image]

as given in above image I have used gridview in yii2. I want to show this web address as link format.

here is code

```
  <?php 
     $gridColumns = [
                    ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
                    ['class' => 'yii\grid\CheckboxColumn'],             
                  ....
                    'name',             
                    'web_address',
                  ...
]; ?>

<?php
            echo GridView::widget([
                'tableOptions' => ['id' => 'companies_grid_table',
                'class' => 'table table-striped table-bordered table-hover'],
                'id'=> 'companies_grid_display',
                'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
                'filterModel' => $searchModel,
                'columns' => $gridColumns,           
            ]); 
?>
```

how to show it as link?

Comment: update your question and add  your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach with sorting enabled :

```
[
    'attribute' => 'web_address',
    'value' => function ($model) {
         return \Yii::$app->formatter->asUrl($model->web_address, ['target' => '_blank']);
     },
    'format' => 'raw',
],
```

Comment: by using your answer and all other aswers search box and sorting options got disable .. any idea why ?

Comment: @ShaileshYadav. These answers has nothing to do with filter. Add your updated code.

Answer (score 2):

In your column you can set the related property with raw format, then use value for build a proper link using`Html` helper: [`Html::a()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-helpers-basehtml.html#a()-detail)

```
[
    'attribute' => 'web_address',
    'label' => 'You Label Name ',
    'format' => 'raw',
    'value' => function ($model) {
         return Html::a('link text', $model->web_address); // your url here
    },
],
```

Comment: @ShaileshYadav add `'attribute' => 'web_address'` to this array

Comment: the order should be managed  by the attribute property .. . i have updated  the answer adding this proprerty too

Answer (score 0):

Please check your field with the following code:

```
[
       'label'=>'Web address',
       'format' => 'raw',
   'value'=>function ($model) {
        return Html::a(Html::encode($model->web_address),$model->web_address);
    },
],
```

**Note**: Use 'format' => 'raw'

Answer (score 0):

Simplest answer is:

```php
....
'name',             
'web_address:url',
...
```

> As a shortcut format, a string may be used to specify the configuration of a data column which only contains attribute, format, and/or label options: "attribute:format:label".

More details [here](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-grid-gridview#$columns-detail).